# What are the different types of implication involved in a type theory setting?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, homotopy-theory, type-theory

I have heard of judgments, entails, usual implies, was just wondering what small subset I actually need to create my own (sort of) type theory (it's a block / arrows app I'm writing).

When do you use entails over usual implies?  Is judgement just a notational thing, i.e. you draw a horizontal line and write above and below it for the hypothesis and conclusion respectively.  If it is just notational, then would you convert it to a usual implies or to an entailment?

More specifically, observe the following diagram:

[image: BananaCats implication arrows, reasoning engine screenshot]

What should the three subscripted $\text{?}$'s be?  I.e. what type of implication.  And lastly what should I call the grouping of two type statements for use in the hypothesis of a judgement?  It's the node at the bottom and currently says "Judgement Hypotheses".

Clearly, logical "or" is handled by natural branching of arrows.  So grouping of the type statements would be inhabitation of *what* type, or do I just color the node differently and call it logical "and"?

The diagram is basically a way to go from type theory to diagram rendering (my app's specialty) using a visual language that specifies what to do.  The language derives its expressive power from the known power of type theory.  A node is nested in a parent node precisely when that parent node is a type and the nested node is an inhabitant.  But perhaps it could mean other things as well.  Not sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with logic, we are proving theorems about how we prove theorems, and so it is important to separate the "meta-logic", which is how we as mathematicians in the outside world reason about thing, from the "inner-logic", which is how somebody using only the tools inside the logic we are studying would reason.

[Judgements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judgment_(mathematical_logic)) define how the inner-logic behaves, and gives us as meta-mathematicians tools for proving that, say, "every inner-logic-provable statement is true of all its models". Judgements turn the inner-logic into a mathematical gadget like any other, which we can reason about. There's no real *need* for the new notation, involving proof trees and horizontal lines. We do it (in part) to make the separation between inner and meta logic clear to the reader (Some authors *don't* do this. It makes reading the paper a nightmare, though.).

Regular Implication, then, is something done *inside* the logic of study. It is the tool that someone living inside the inner-logic would use to prove things, blissfully unaware of the meta-mathematical tools which lie beyond their reach.

The confusion is made worse because we as humans know how logic *should* work, and so we often try to make our inner-logic behave in a similar way to our meta-logic. For instance, we almost always include a rule like the following:

[image: -> introduction]

This rule tells us how to prove (in the meta-language) that $A \to B$ is *provable* in the inner-language. $A \to B$ is provable (in the inner-language) whenever we can prove $B$ using $A$ an additional assumption (again, in the inner-language).

[This](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/judgment) article talks about judgements, and is both good and short. [This book](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/pfpl/) might also clarify things by putting judgements in a more general light - it discusses programming languages, and how to formalize them as logics (with type theory). It's a bit long, but if you only read the first few chapters you might see another way of thinking about how judgements (in the meta logic) correspond to properties which are provable (in the inner logic).

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Yes, this helps.  I will read the article and your post a few times :)  Also see edits to my post and subsequent questions regarding what the $\text{?}$ labels should be.

Comment: I'm still confused by your digram-notation. What you do want the above picture to represent? I'm happy with "node1 inside node2 means node1 : node2". I'm not sure what you what the external arrows to represent.

Comment: Those particular arrows should be double-lines (have to code that) as a sort of logical implication.  Associativity of (true) implications means those nodes are objects in the category of true "things you can say or typing" where arrows are implications.  I'm just wondering what "kind" of implication they should be: judgment, entailment, semantic entailment, or simply inner-implies (inner as you were referring to).  For example, if the arrow should be entailment I can label it with a $\vdash$.  Also the labels can be intro-elim. rule names e.g. "identity" would take $\text{?}_1$'s place.

Comment: Oh yeah forgot to mention.  If a type node has a rule arrow going from it, you treat the node as if it were contained in another node called "hypothesis of the rule".  But it would be weird to have another node containing only a single node for that purpose, so when there's a single node in a hypotesis, it's exactly the same (I'm coding it to be this way) as if the arrow came from the inner (parented) type node.  It's just a shorthand for elegance, just as we do in math.

Comment: Wrapping up the above, the $\text{?}_*$'s should either be a rule name (perhaps with a $\vdash$ as on nlab article (in my original post), or they should be just a logical implication itself.  So please enlighten me on which arrow best fits what.  Also there's the $\text{hom}_C(a,a) \Rightarrow \text{hom}_C(a, b=a)$ a sort of "substitution implication"  where I'm seeing, if there is a string hom from the implied to the hypothesis, then their is an implication there.  The string hom is a special idea which requires careful handling of variables, but it is indeed codable. How to do subst. imply?

Comment: Lastly, to complete the picture in your mind.  The $D : \text{Diagram}$ is a special type and it means that there is a diagram named $D$ and it has an associated graphics view (the Diagram widget) and a diagram scene.  And inhabitants of the Diagram (nodes or arrows essentially, even nested nodes / arrows) *are to be drawn*.  So it's like a type but handled in a special way for the sake of doing human-computer output display.  So as you can see that's how I've decied to connect type theory with diagram rendering.  It makes the most natural sense to me (for the sake of doing category theory).

Comment: Note, that although my first goal is presentation of diagrams for category theory and active logic behind the diagram, the diagrams can be *anything* so nodes within nodes, arrows between arrows, and so-on... So it's like a general tool.

Comment: Forgot to mention, you're not seeing, and I shouldn't display, every definition involved.  But you see part of the definition of identity, and also part of the definition of $\text{hom}_C(a,b)$.  Either that or your seeing the rules actually being applied.  The final thing proved is that $1_a : a \to a$ can be drawn as an arrow inside of a general category diagram.  The user doesn't usually see it this way though, they just "draw an arrow" with the mouse and label it as $\text{id}_a$ or "take an identity" arrow (action in the context menu when right clicking an object in a category diagram).

Comment: Finally, the diagrams will also be used to define the diagram transformation rules.  Such as "take a functor named $F$" into this other diagram $E$ (or the same diagram optionally painting it in place or in a copy of the diagram).  By the way, object / arrow positioning is automatically reflected from input to output of an arrow, so when the functor image is taken, I have to put into the language a mechanism for "reflect positions".  Stuff like that... by now I'm babbeling.

Comment: That just gave me an idea... there should be another type of "thin-lined" arrow that shows what positions are reflected where.   Since that is the most general and elegant way to handle it given that we're already doing blocks and arrows.  I could have a global setting for "reflect positions as specified" in the edit menu.

Comment: Take your time on this.  Feel free to post an independent answer.